# how to create a swapping function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i basically want to swap the content of 2 variables using a function either in jquery or javascript. and i cont have a bias against any method.(it won't make difference using a temporary variable or not using it)
I tried this in javascript

```
function swap(x,y){

      x = x + y;
      y = x - y;
      x = x - y;
      return x,y
    }
    var two = 1;
    var one= 2;
    swap (one,two);
    document.write(one);
```

Comment: That's not how variables work.

Comment: `[one, two] = [two, one];`

Comment: You need to include the relevant error messages or an example of how it is failing within your question, Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @stefan i debugged it and it didn't seem to have a problem but it just doesn't work

Comment: @Slaks how do they work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code. It seems like you are not familiar with how datastructures and variable/functions work in Javascript. I strongly recommend you learn about them first.

Your `swap` function takes 2 arguments `x` and `y` and does some mathematical operations on it which would swap the values. Here, you are making the assumption that the variables will always be a number or a type of variable where addition and subtraction would make sense. Unless you can assure that variables will always be numbers, this is the wrong approach.

Similarly, your return statement is `return x, y`. You cannot return 2 variables from a function. Output from a function is a single value. In this case, since you need 2 variables to be returned, you should use a composite structure like an array / object.

The value returned from this function needs to be stored in appropriate variables so that you can use them. Line number 10 in your code calls the method, but does not store its return value anywhere.

Generic solution for your use case will be as follows

```
// Create two variables
let x = 1, y = 2;

function swap(x, y) {
  // Return the 2 variables in swapped order
  return [y, x]
};

// Call the swap function and assign the return values back to the variables
[x, y] = swap(x, y);

// Print to console to verify
console.log(x, y);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any addition or subtraction in the function; you can simply return `y` and then `x`. However, note that you can't return two values at once from a function -- you'll need to return then as an array (that optionally gets converted to a string), if you want to return them both at the same time.

```js
function swap(x, y) {
  return [y, x].toString();
}

console.log(swap(1, 2));
```